# This site can’t be reached/404 status code after setting headers in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, http-headers

I want to force download of xlsx file that is generated dynamically in payments-exports.php file.

The problem is that if I set headers, using the header() function I get This site can't be reached error, with 404 status visible in developer tools.

This is the anchor element that initiates file download located in admin-dash.php:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( project_name_get_permalink( 'admin- 
dash/payments-export/' ) . $endpoint_part ); ?>" class=""><?php 
esc_html_e( 'Export to .xls', 'project_name' ); ?></a>
```

The payments-export.php file(sub-endpoint of admin-dash):

```
// this is at the top of the file
die('test');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.xlsx"' );

//die('test2');
// I cant see "test2" if I uncomment it and remove the first die function

// generate the file
....
$writer->writeToStdOut();

exit();
```

I can see test displaying on my screen normally,but when I remove it, I get

> This site can’t be reached

If I remove the die() and header() functions completely,I get the generated output visible on the screen, without any errors.

Basically the correct file is opened, file contents are generated correctly, but setting headers stops the execution of the script and throws an error.

Comment: you need to echo or print out the data after setting the headers then exit()

Comment: I'm doing that already, the problem is that the script stops with its execution after setting the first header, and never get to that part, I'll add that part to the question to make it more clear.

Comment: header() can be finicky for good measure can you try removing all extra whitespace on the outer ends of your in header calls, basically a trim()

Comment: Thanks, for the tip, I removed all the whitespaces, but unfortunately I still get the same error.

Comment: From the PHP documentation : "Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file. ". Did you check every file for extra empty lines after ?> tags, ... ?